# Android application name logger

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to figure out how to do the following:
I want to make a service which will log all the activities / applications (names, their start time, end time and exceptions) also log where the user touched the screen. Is there a way to do it without parsing LogCat ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could build a string of events that occur in each stage of your program, and then write them to a file in the overridden onPause, onDestroy, etc. methods.

see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Either that or learn how to use the intent filters on adb! There are a few tutorials you can use for this.

Comment: Well yes, but I want to make something like keylogger but for apps - applogger. Not only to log my own apps but others too. Example: If user started "Radio" i want to log it.

Comment: Ah, well check out broadcast intents, anytime an activity is started, or changed, a broadcast message goes out. You could use a service to log this broadcast message, and the front end of the application could be used to email the log to yourself.

see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html